# One out of 2 buttons initiate scroll but both of them are supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a long page with one button at tope and one button at the bottom , i made the first button scroll me to a div tag at the botton like this

```
 <button onClick="document.getElementById('middle').scrollIntoView();" >

 <b>
    Learn More.
 </b>
 </button>`
```

But the second button with the same code but the middle changed to top doesnt work

```
    <button onClick="document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView();" , class = 'goback ' >

    <b>
        Go Back Up
    </b>
    </button>
```

and i donot have any solution for this , am i missing something silly?

Comment: In second code there is issue in writing class there is a comma before class.

Comment: I tried out your code on my computer, it is working properly. So, there might be an issue in the code that you have not mentioned. For example, the name of the `id` might be incorrect, etc.

Comment: @ShyamakSeth pointed out an issue which should be addressed - please create a fiddle if you still cannot get it to work.  For more info than you wanted, this is a good guide: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/scroll-to-the-top-of-page-1cce3446808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be better if you didn't use Javascript as some users disable it entirely when visiting websites.

Wrap an `<a>` tag around your buttons and use the `href` attribute instead.

```css
section {
  height: 70vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="first-section">
  <a href="#second-section"><button>Go to second section</button></a>
</section>
<section id="second-section">
  <a href="#first-section"><button>Go to first section</button></a>
</section>
```

Comment: i did this , i created 2 sections and linked them and added scroll behavior as smooth , worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you have to add id to the tag

```html
<button onClick="document.getElementById('middle').scrollIntoView();">
  <b>
    Learn More.
  </b>
</button>`

<div id="top" style="height: 400px">
top content
</div>
<div id="middle" style="height: 400px">
middle content
</div>
<div style="height: 400px">
content
</div>


<button onClick="document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView();" class='goback '>
  <b>
    Go Back Up
  </b>
</button>
```